# Should I partial trace the hamiltonian or partition function for a reduced system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, hamiltonian, partition-function

Suppose I have a quantum spin model, let's say e.g. the quantum transverse field model with hamiltonian $H$, on some lattice of particles, with partition function $\text{Tr}(e^{- \beta H})$  and I do a local measurement of a specific particle $i$ in the $\sigma_z$ basis. Let's say I do find spin up for particle $i$, and I want to investigate the system given this information. Would this be the same as considering a new Hamiltonian  defined as
$$
\tilde{H} = \left(I \otimes \langle \uparrow| \right) H  \left(I \otimes | \uparrow \rangle \right),
$$
(which is kinda similar to a partial trace of $H$), and then consider the new partition function $\text{Tr}(e^{-\beta \tilde{H}})$.

Or should the partition function still involve the original hamiltonian, but instead of taking the normal trace of $e^{ -\beta H}$, I look at the following object:
$$
\sum_{\phi, \phi_i= \uparrow} \langle \phi | e^{-\beta H} | \phi \rangle,
$$
where $\phi$ ranges over all standard basis vectors (i.e. tensor products of $\sigma_z$ basis) but conditioned on the fact that we have spin up for the $i-$th position. (Note that without this last condition, it would just be the normal trace again. This of course is not a partial trace, but I guess we could call it something similar like that.)

Which of the two "partition functions" of the reduced system makes more sense?

Comment: What is the motivation behind this question? Why not simply calculating the reduced density matrix of the corresponding subsystem?

Comment: The motivation is to try to use some techniques of classical statistical mechanics in a generalized quantum case, in which I want to study zero free regions of the partition function in the complex plane (implying the absence of phase transitions in those areas).  In the classical case it's useful to work with partition functions for the case where certain vertices are already fixed to be a specific state (as a tool)

Comment: Why do people vote for close without commenting what kind of clarity it needs?

Comment: @user3397129 I didn't vote so, but I *do* think the scenario is unclear. What do you mean by "Would this be the same as considering"? It is clear what the condition density matrix (i.e., "Gibbs state") is, but is is completely unclear what a conditional partition function is. You'll have to define what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

No, the first approach is not correct.

E.g., take a 3-site Heisenberg chain with open boundary conditions, where you project the middle spin onto $\lvert\uparrow\rangle$. Then, you can easily check that if you do this on the Gibbs state for very large $\beta$ (a mixed state of the two degenerate ground states), there are correlations between the left and right particle. On the other hand, if you first project your Hamiltonian, and then take the Gibbs state, one spin will point up and the other will point down, with no correlations.

Now your question is about the partition function, i.e. the trace of the Gibbs state. But since it contains all information about the state, if you allow for arbitrary derivatives, it also will fail for the partition function. (However, I would say that the "conditional partition function" is really not a very well-defined object, so it seems to me. Thus, what you really should be thinking about is the conditional Gibbs state, about which I talk above. If you think your "conditional partition function" is by itself meaningful, you will have to define what this is supposed to mean.)

(Note that it even fails on an earlier level for the partition function: Just take a single Heisenberg Hamiltonian: The ground state has energy $-3$, but after your projection rule it has energy $-1$.)

The other rule, on the other hand, is by construction the correct one to obtain the Gibbs state after the projection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding the second object, (the conditional partition function), doesn't it have quite a meaning. Because it seems that the probability that you measure spin up for particle $i$ is actually given by this "conditional partition function" divided by the normal partition function.

Comment: @user3397129 If you think there is a clear notion: Please edit the question, and provide a detailed, specific, and tangible (formulas! clear statements!) explanation. Otherwise, I am unable to comment on it.

Answer (score -1):

Both of the suggestions you have written down could be used to study a system where one of the spins is measured *and then pinned to the result of the measurement from that point on-words*. This is, however, not a particularly common situation, unless you are considering measurements taken a very short time apart.

The standard tool for studying these types experiments where you are interested in "measuring $A$ given $B$" are two point correlation functions
$$
\langle A(t_2) B(t_1) \rangle 
$$
where $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ are the Heisenberg picture operators for the observables you are considering. This object includes the full evolution of both the measured and unmeasured parts of the system together.

There are a wide array of other tools that can be used in this type of problem, but the essential point is to continue to use the full Hamiltonian and evolve the full state, including the measured degree of freedom, from the state post measurement (or at least some approximation to this scheme).

Comment: But I am not interested in a time evolutions, so we could say at a fixed point in time. I'm only interested in the behaviour of the system as the temperature, interaction energy and external field change,

Comment: There is no mention about time evolution in the system. The question seems to be about the Gibbs state, conditioned on the measurement outcome.

Comment: So indeed, it is really pinned.  But then, I still wouldn't be sure which approach makes more sense.